# Why does localStorage.Remove not work? React

Tags: reactjs

```
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function RequireAuth({ children }) {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const location = useLocation();



if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to='/' state={{ from: location }} replace />;
}

return children;
}


export default RequireAuth;
```

```
import MotionLeftSideSignin from '../components/MotionSignIn/motionsigninleftside.js';
import SignUpBar from '../components/MotionSignIn/SignupBar.js';
import { MainContainer,SignInContainer,RightContainer,Header,Inputboxes,UsernameInput,PasswordnameInput,SigninbuttonBox,SigninButton} from '../style/signinStyle.js';
import { useState } from 'react';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';


const Signin = () => {
    const [email,setEmail] = useState();
    const [password,setPassword] = useState();
    const navigate= useNavigate();
    
    const updateEmail = (event) =>{
        setEmail(event.target.value);
    }
    const updatePassword = (event) =>{
        setPassword(event.target.value);
    }
    const login = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        const url = "https://motion.propulsion-home.ch/backend/api/auth/token/"
        const data = {
            email:email,
            password:password,
        };
        const fetchConfig = {
            method:"POST",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }),
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
        fetch(url,fetchConfig)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            if(data.access === undefined) {
                alert("Please try again")
            }else{
                localStorage.setItem('token',data.access);
                navigate("/Posts")
            };
            
            
            
        });
```

```
const NavigationBar = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const toFriendsPage = () => {
        navigate("/FindFriends");
    }
    const toSignInPage = () =>{
        navigate("/");
    }
    const toPostsPage = () =>{
        navigate("/Posts");
    }

    const togglePopUp = () => {
        const popUp = document.querySelector(".popup")
        const popUpDisplay = window.getComputedStyle( popUp, null ).display

        if (popUpDisplay === "flex") {
            popUp.style.display = "none"
        } else {
            popUp.style.display = "flex"
        }
    }
    
    const logOut = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        
    
    }
    
    return (
        <ProfilOverlayHeader>
            <NavigationBarLogoDiv>
                <NavigationBarLogo src={logo} alt="logo"/>
                <NavigationBarTitle onClick={toSignInPage}>Motion</NavigationBarTitle>
            </NavigationBarLogoDiv>
            <Post_FriendsDiv>
                <Post_FriendsDivPosts>
                    <Post_FriendsDivPostsImg src={postsImg} alt="posts"/>
                    <Clickables onClick={toPostsPage}>Posts</Clickables>
                </Post_FriendsDivPosts>
                <Post_FriendsDivFriendsImg src={friendsImg} alt="friends"/>
                <Clickables onClick={toFriendsPage}>Find Friends</Clickables>
            </Post_FriendsDiv>
            <Notif_ProfilPic_SettingsDiv>
                <NotificationBell src={notificationBellImg} alt="your notifications"/>
                <NavigationBarProfilPic onClick={ togglePopUp } src={profilPic} alt="your profil picture"/>
                <ProfilPopUpDiv className="popup">
                <TopDiv>
                    <ProfileIcon src={ ProfilePopUpIcon } alt="profile icon"/>
                    <p>Profile</p>
                </TopDiv>
                <BottomDiv>
                    <LogOutIcon src={ LogoutIcon } alt="profile icon"/>
                    <LogOutButton onclick={logOut}>Logout</LogOutButton>
```

```
import './App.css';
import SignIn from './pages/signin.js';
import SignUpStep1 from './pages/signup-step1.js'
import {Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import SignUpStep2 from './pages/signup-step2.js'
import Verification from './pages/verification.js'
import Posts from './pages/posts-pages/PostsPage.js'
import FindFriends from './pages/find-friends-pages/FindFriendsPage.js'
import RequireAuth from './components/Auth/RequireAuth.js'
import ProfilOverlay3_1 from "./pages/ProfilOverlay3_1";
import ProfilOverlay3_2 from "./pages/ProfilOverlay3_2";
import ProfilOverlay3_3 from "./pages/ProfilOverlay3_3";
import ProfilOverlay3_4 from './pages/ProfilOverlay3_4';


function App() {
  return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<SignIn/>} />
    <Route path="/SignUpStep1" element={<SignUpStep1/>} />
    <Route path="/SignUpStep2" element={<SignUpStep2/>} />
    <Route path="/Verification" element={<Verification/>} />
    <Route path="/Posts" element={<RequireAuth><Posts/></RequireAuth>} />
    <Route path= "/FindFriends" element={<RequireAuth><FindFriends/></RequireAuth>} />
    <Route path="/ProfilPosts" element={<RequireAuth><ProfilOverlay3_1/></RequireAuth>}/>
    <Route path="/ProfilEdit" element={ <RequireAuth><ProfilOverlay3_2/></RequireAuth> } />
    <Route path="/UserPosts" element= { <RequireAuth><ProfilOverlay3_3/> </RequireAuth>} />
    <Route path="/UserFriends" element= {<RequireAuth><ProfilOverlay3_4 /> </RequireAuth>} />
  </Routes> 

  // <FindFriendsNotification />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Hi I have added an authentication using a JSON Web Token for a react project i'm working on from a bootcamp (so i am very new to this). The authentication works for registration , login and browser refresh. But when I call the logOut function on the onClick logout button it doesn't log me out. I have console logged localStorage.getItem('token') before and after the logout function. The first console log is present and the second not, so I guess it has removed the token but then it doesn't redirect me to the signin page. Also if i refresh it stays on the same page. Does anyone know why this is happening? thanks

Comment: It's not visible in the code fragments you've posted where/how the RequireAuth component is used.

Comment: sorry you are right. I have added it now

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined variable `token` makes it static:
`const token = localStorage.getItem('token');`

You only run this once at the start of routes using `RequireAuth`, and I'm guessing it doesn't run after you update your local storage, therefore even though you removed the token, the component never updates.

I personally would use the React Context API to handle issues like this. But for the sake of just implementing the function, you can always hard-code a `navigate('/')` function after logging out.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did also try to hardcode "navigate('/')" but it still didn't work.